# Auto-scaling VMs in Azure--only contains one virtual machine, but I have two?

Tags: azure, autoscaling

I have two Standard A0 VMs, entitled "testing-a-vm" and "testing-a-vm2", and I put them both in the availability set "sample-set".

When I visit the dashboard for either VM, there is a "CONFIGURE AUTOSCALE" link. If I click that, I am taken to the "SCALE" tab, where it says

> This availability set contains only one virtual machine. Add more virtual machines to it to start autoscaling.

But... both of these VMs are show the availability set "sample-set" on their "Configure" tabs.

I'm thinking I placed them in the set wrong. For the first one, on the "Configure" tab, I chose "Create an availability set", and typed "sample-set" for the name.

I then created a second VM, and when asked what availability set to place it in, I did not see my set. It was not an option. So I choose "Create new" and typed the exact same name, "sample-set".

I can only assume something went awry at this step. How am I supposed to add a second VM to an *existing* availability set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found after some additional experimenting is that, when creating the virtual machine, I needed to select the name of my first vm, "testing-a-vm", from the dropbox box labeled "CLOUD SERVICE". This appears during the setup of the "Virtual machine configuration."

Going back and reviewing the "Configure" tab for "testing-a-vm2", I don't see any way to define the "CLOUD SERVICE" value after the VM has been created.

Once I created a new VM, and placed it in the "CLOUD SERVICE" with the same name as my initial VM, I was able to configure autoscaling on my availability set.